# It shows attribute error after providing the link and hitting enter.(using kivy)

Tags: python, youtube, kivy

**This is the main python file:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from pytube import YouTube

kv = """
Screen:

    MDLabel:
        text: 'YT Video Downloader'
        font_style: 'H2'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.8}

    MDTextField:
        id: txt
        hint_text: 'Enter the url of your video'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 300
        icon_right: 'youtube'


    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Submit'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        on_press:
            app.download()
"""


class Main(MDApp):
    txt = ObjectProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def download(self):

        url = self.ids.txt.text
        video = YouTube(url)
        video_streams = video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').get_by_itag(18)
        video_streams.download()


Main().run()
```

On running, I am able to enter text but unable to refer the entered text so as to download the file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For your `App` object, or in this case `MDApp`, specifically, you have to use `self.root.ids` instead of `self.ids` to access widgets. Imagine it the same way how you access other root widgets in your .kv file/string using `root.ids`

```
def download(self):

        url = self.root.ids.txt.text
        video = YouTube(url)
        video_streams = video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').get_by_itag(18)
        video_streams.download()
```

And hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to be clearer and more detailed about what you want to do, what went wrong, stuff like that, since spamming like this can easily get your question closed or flagged for `very low quality` or `needs improvement`.